# Pass current dbName and execute procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

See this...

```
SELECT * 
INTO #WL_Klijenti
FROM  OPENROWSET ('SQLOLEDB','Server=(local);TRUSTED_CONNECTION=YES;','SET 
FMTONLY OFF; SET NOCOUNT ON; EXEC 
WBANKA_KBBL2.dbo.sp_kbbl_WachLista_Priprema ''2017.09.30'', ''2017.09.30'', 
0')
    AS tbl
```

> The part : EXEC WBANKA_KBBL2 should be replaced with the current db used, so that the user does not have to specify it manualy.

I had an idea of a procedure with an output parameter which will return current database and store it in a variable and this was my try:

SP Looks like this:

```
CREATE procedure dbo.getCurrentDB
(

@dbName varchar(30) OUTPUT

)
AS

BEGIN

set @dbName = (select db_name())
--select @dbName

END
go
```

---

*How can I pass my current db used to the procedure call, instead of specifying it manually?*

EDIT:

When I run it like this I receive **A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations**

```
declare @dbName varchar(30)
exec getCurrentDB @dbName output

DECLARE @ORS varchar(MAX);


SELECT @ORS = 'Server=(local);TRUSTED_CONNECTION=YES;','SET 
FMTONLY OFF; SET NOCOUNT ON; exec
select ' + QUOTENAME([name] + '.dbo.sp_kbbl_WachLista_Priprema 
''2017.09.30'', ''2017.09.30'', 
0')
FROM sys.databases
WHERE [name] = @dbName

SELECT * 
INTO #WL_Klijenti
FROM  OPENROWSET ('SQLOLEDB',@ORS)
 AS tbl;
```

Comment: What should happen when user runs this from master database

Comment: Slight detour, you should avoid using the sp_ prefix, use a different prefix or even better no prefix at all. The sp_ prefix can cause lots of issues. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix